# liferay 7.1 b3 embed portlet in fragment

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, liferay-7

I'm trying out [liferay 7.1 b3](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/7.1.0-b3) and I'd like to embed a portlet in a page fragment. I've taken a look at the most recent documentation available [here](https://dev.liferay.com/de/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-1/fragment-specific-tags), which says that in order to embed a portlet widget in a page fragment, all I have to do is add the

```
"com.liferay.fragment.entry.processor.portlet.alias=my-custom-portlet"
```

property in the `@Component` properties, where in this case, the alias (`my-custom-portlet`) is the alias I will use to include the portlet in the fragment.

Then in my custom page fragment I have to include the `lfr-widget` tag with the suffix defined by the `com.liferay.fragment.entry.processor.portlet.alias` propertiy. So in my case, it should be`<lfr-widget-my-custom-portlet />`.

The trouble is that I can't even create the page fragment with the above. I get the following error:

> There is no widget available for alias my-custom-portlet.

If, on the other hand, I try it with a liferay portlet (such as `<lfr-widget-nav/>` in their own example) the nav portlet is correctly displayed. Has anyone else tried? Any feedback at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. There were a couple things to consider.

First, I generated the mvc-portlet with Eclipse and it put old versions of the kernel dependencies in the build.gradle file. I changed them to:

```
compileOnly group: 'com.liferay.portal', name: 'com.liferay.portal.kernel', version: '3.0.1'
compileOnly group: 'com.liferay.portal', name: 'com.liferay.util.taglib', version: '3.0.0'
```

Second, in the portlet's `@Component` annotation in the `property { ... }` list I added:

```
"com.liferay.fragment.entry.processor.portlet.alias=my-custom-portlet",
"com.liferay.portlet.application-type=widget",
"com.liferay.portlet.application-type=full-page-application",
"javax.portlet.name=my-custom-portlet",
```

in addition to what was already there.

So in my case, the **`@Component`** looks like

```
@Component(
    immediate = true,
    property = {
        "com.liferay.portlet.display-category=category.sample",
        "com.liferay.portlet.instanceable=true",
        "javax.portlet.display-name=my-custom-portlet Portlet",
        "javax.portlet.init-param.template-path=/",
        "javax.portlet.init-param.view-template=/view.jsp",
        "javax.portlet.resource-bundle=content.Language",
        "javax.portlet.security-role-ref=power-user,user",
        "javax.portlet.name=my-custom-portlet",
        "com.liferay.fragment.entry.processor.portlet.alias=my-custom-portlet",
        "com.liferay.portlet.application-type=widget",
        "com.liferay.portlet.application-type=full-page-application",
        "com.liferay.portlet.add-default-resource=true"
    },
    service = Portlet.class
)
public class MyCustomPortlet extends MVCPortlet {
```

and the **`build.gradle`** file looks like

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly group: 'com.liferay.portal', name: 'com.liferay.portal.kernel', version: '3.0.1'
    compileOnly group: 'com.liferay.portal', name: 'com.liferay.util.taglib', version: '3.0.0'

    compileOnly group: "javax.portlet", name: "portlet-api", version: "2.0"
    compileOnly group: "javax.servlet", name: "javax.servlet-api", version: "3.0.1"
    compileOnly group: "jstl", name: "jstl", version: "1.2"
    compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "osgi.cmpn", version: "6.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and the solution for me was to avoid dashes in the portlet name! It took me waay to long to figure it out, so i thought i will post it here if someone has the same problem and comes across this post.
So instead of `"javax.portlet.name=my-custom-portlet"` write `"javax.portlet.name=myCustomPortlet"` for example.
The Fragment property can still include any dashes: `"com.liferay.fragment.entry.processor.portlet.alias=my-custom-portlet"`

Comment: Fortunately I'm not working with liferay portlets anymore but I'm glad you found an answer that works. Hopefully it can help someone out, it's much simpler than the solution I posted.

Answer (score 0):

With dxp 7.2 embedding the portlet failed when I used the constant value from the exported constant package as portlet name as provided by the blade  template. After removing the constant and using just a string with javax.portlet.name (as shown in the answer of geco17 above) it worked.